# Scrapy: return FormRequest in Downloader Middleware

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

A website I am scraping sometimes redirects to a page with a form which I would like to handle in the Downloader Middleware. The idea is that every time this redirect occurs, it automatically submits the form and retrieve the results. My middleware looks something like:

```py
from scrapy import FormRequest

class SubmitFormMiddleware:
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.css('form.loginbox').getall():
            post_form_url = response.css('form.loginbox::attr(action)').get()
            return FormRequest(url=response.urljoin(post_form_url),
                                     formdata={'username': 'my_username',
                                               'password': 'my_password',
                                               'data_selection': 'all'
                                               },
                                     method='POST',
                                     dont_filter=True)
        else:
            return response
```

This doesn't work since I don't have any callback defined (and I shouldn't because I am in middleware):

```
NotImplementedError: DefaultSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

If I wanted to just return a request I would have something like:

```
redirected = request.replace(url=response.urljoin(post_form_url))
return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, response.status)
```

but this does not work for submitting a form. Does anybody know what the 'Scrapy-thonic' way is to use the FormRequest in a Downloader Middleware?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error, I can yield a FormRequest exactly the way you wrote it.  Are you sure the error is linked to the middleware and you're not just missing a parse method in your spider?

Comment: I do have a parse function in my spider. However, at the moment I am calling `scrapy shell "my_website.com"`, so my spider is not used, but the middlewares are.

Comment: @WimHermans, would it be possible to add something like `callback=response.request.callback` to the `FormRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem in the following way:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest

class SubmitFormMiddleware:
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.css('form.loginbox').getall():
            post_form_url = response.css('form.loginbox::attr(action)').get()
            form_request_handle = FormRequest(url=response.urljoin(post_form_url),
                                     formdata={'username': 'my_username',
                                               'password': 'my_password',
                                               'data_selection': 'all'
                                               },
                                     method='POST',
                                     dont_filter=True)
            return request.replace(url=form_request_handle.url,
                                     method='POST',
                                     body=form_request_handle.body,
                                     headers=form_request_handle.headers,
                                     dont_filter=True)
        else:
            return response
```

Although this works, I am still curious about the 'scrapy-thonic' way to solve submit a `FormRequest` in the middleware.